# What's the maximum size Content extract possible with Tridion CP 2009 SP1?

Tags: tridion

I'm getting "Content too large" errors at ~ 120MB.  Is this a hard limit or is it possible to extend via settings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ASFAIK, there are no hard limits at the content porter level. However, IIS has default 30 MB limit on file uploads. You  can increase the value in web.config to higher value based on your needs.
Reference Link on increasing the limit: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_ContentPorter_2009_SP1/task_CCFED8DFFA9A4E138DEA72FBDF4C18AD

```
<system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="209715200"/>
</system.web>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209752100" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

The above config value in web.config will set the limit to 200 MB.

Do not forget to start the Tridion core services, content porter service and IIS reset after the changes done.

Hope this information helps.